# Rails 3: How to save links in a model variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm creating a newsfeed and It'd be helpful if I could save links in the model variable content (for example).

Can that be done?

Thanks

**Edit: what I want is to store in the variable :content something like: Donald(link to donald profile) has bought a box(link to box page) from user_x(link to user_x store).**

Answer (score 1):

So you basically want to create a link from relations. You should *NOT* store the raw link in your database, but rather build it dynamically (imagine if an id changed or a product id changed). If I understand your example correctly, a purchase is a self-referencing join between users? [See here for implementation setup](http://blog.hasmanythrough.com/2007/10/30/self-referential-has-many-through)

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def profile_link
    link_to "#{self.first_name} #{self.last_name}", user_profile_path(self)
  end

  def store_link
    link_to "#{self.first_name} #{self.last_name}", user_store_path(self)
  end
end

class Purchase < ActiveRecord::Base
  def product_link
    link_to self.product_name, product_path(self)
  end

  # buyer and seller are the aliases for the self referencing user class
  def info_link
    "#{self.buyer.profile_link} has bought a #{self.product_link} from #{seller.store_link}"
  end
end
```

where url and title are fields in your table (that you created and populated)

Then in your view:

```
stuff... <%= @product.info_link %>
```